# How can I create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, usb

With Windows you can easily make a bootable USB drive using Universal USB Installer. How can I make a bootable USB drive using Ubuntu? Universal USB installer, Unetbootin, Rufus, etc. are only for Windows.

Comment: Short answer: type `usb-creator-gtk`.

Comment: `sudo dd if=linux-os.iso of=/dev/usbstick` no software to install like in windows. how can it be any faster?

Comment: **Mkusb** https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb Can make a Live USB for use as an installer only or It can make a bootable drive with boot partitions for BIOS/UEFI, read only ISO9660 OS partition, ext2 casper-rw persistence partition and NTFS data partition accessible by Linux or Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **Startup Disk Creator**. If you don't have it installed, you can install it via *Ubuntu Software*.
After you run it, you have to choose the path to you `iso` file and select the disk to use (the USB Drive). Then press the button **Make Startup Disk**.

[image]